# Adjusting height of rotated symbol

Tags: symbols, rotating

I am trying to replicate the following symbol that's in between the two M's:

[image]

I assume it is `\exists` rotated by -90°. When trying to rotate it via `\rotatebox`, the symbol doesn't lie flat anymore however, no matter what `origin` parameter I choose. For example, take a look at the following:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
$A \: \rotatebox[origin=B]{-90}{$\exists$} \: B$
\end{document}
```

This results in the correct symbol, but it is placed lower than I would want it to be. Is there any way I can now adjust the height of the symbol so that it looks like in the image above?

Comment: I have managed to get a somewhat better approximation by adding a space to the box and rotating around the center (i.e. `$A \: \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{ $\exists$} \: B$`), but this feels a bit artificial and still doesn't exactly fit.

Comment: shuffle product U+2E92 ⧢ ? `\shuffle` in unicode-math or stix packages

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's the one, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to rotation you may be able to use `⧢` Unicode U+2E92 (Shuffle Product) . This is available in any Unicode Math font as used by `unicode-math` where it is also available via the command `\shuffle`. The command `\shuffle` is also supported by some pdflatex math font packages, notably `stix2`.